# Exibição de uma tabela mysql na página html

Tags: php, html

Bom dia amigos! 
Pesquisando, consegui juntar esse código da página 'mostratestem' para expor o conteúdo  da tabela 'testemunho' do BD 'beja_provida'. Todavia, não da o resultado esperado. Alguém me da uma luz, por favor?
Codigo:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <title>ListaTestem</title>
 </head>
<body>

<h1>Exibir dados com PHP/MySql</h1>

<?php

$servidor = "localhost"; /*maquina a qual o banco de dados está*/
$usuario = "root"; /*usuario do banco de dados MySql*/
$senha = "joanin21"; /*senha do banco de dados MySql*/
$banco = "beja_provida"; /*seleciona o banco a ser usado*/

$conexao = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha);  /*Conecta no bando de dados MySql*/

mysqli_select_db($banco); /*seleciona o banco a ser usado*/

$res = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM testemunho ORDER BY nome")or die (mysqli_error($escrever); /*Executa o comando SQL, no caso para pegar todos os usuarios do sistema e retorna o valor da consulta em uma variavel ($res)  */

echo "<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Nome</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Testemunho</td></tr>";

/*Enquanto houver dados na tabela para serem mostrados será executado tudo que esta dentro do while */
while($escrever=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

/*Escreve cada linha da tabela*/
echo "<tr><td>" . $escrever['id_testem'] . $escrever['nome'] . "</td><td>" . $escrever['email'] . "</td><td>" . $escrever['testemunho'] . "</td></tr>";

} /*Fim do while*/

echo "</table>"; /*fecha a tabela apos termino de impressão das linhas*/

mysql_close(conexao);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]
O HTML que chama a página 'mostratestem' é esta:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Savino</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="provida.js"></script>
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="provida.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="fundo-externo">
 <div id="fundo">
  <img src="imgPv/providaUfpa.png" alt="Provida" />
 </div>
</div>
<div id="site">
<h1>TESTEMUNHOS</h1></a>
<h1><strong><a href="savinoPortugues.html" alt="Apresentação" style="text-decoration:none">“ o Reino de Deus è a coordenação de todas as forças positivas que existem no mundo a fim de que consigam transformar a vida numa nova e apreciável realidade sem dores, sem fome, sem guerras, sem doenças   <br>e   nenhum   outro   mal."</u>. <br>(Savino Mombelli)</a></strong></h1>
<div id="menu">
<a href="./savinoPortugues.html" style="text-decoration:none">Savino</a>
<a href="./impressos/historiaPadreSavino.pdf"target="_blank"style="text-decoration:none">Histórico</a>
<a href="./impressos.html" style="text-decoration:none">Reflexões</a>
<a href="./imagSv.html"style="text-decoration:none">Imagens</a><br><br>
</div>
<div>
 <form action="testemunho.php" method="post">
            Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" size="50" />
            <br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="50" />
            <br>
   Testemunho: <textarea name="testemunho" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea> <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
        </form> 
        <?php include("mostratestem.php"); ?>
</div>
<BLOCKQUOTE>
  <p>
  *<a href="./mostratestem.html"style="text-decoration:none"><h3>Veja os testemunhos registrados</h3></a><br><br>*
  <h2>PÁGINA EM COSTRUÇÃO </h2>
  </p>
 </BLOCKQUOTE>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Na pagina *testemunho.php* essa parte aqui está aberta `or die (mysqli_error($escrever);` falta `)` para fechar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu estava passando por este problema, mas agora consegui resolver há alguns dias e vou postar meu código aqui é uma tabela com dados trazidos do banco de dados, e desta forma eu tiro somente o cabeçalho do PHP e deixo dentro do HTML mesmo. Meu include no arquivo `conn.php` é feito pois, este arquivo que faz conexão com o banco de dados.

index.php ( teste isso com valores do seu Banco de Dados )

```
<table border = '2'>

<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Código Produto</th>
  <th>Tipo</th>
  <th>Descricao</th>
</tr>

<?php include("conn.php");

$sql_tipo = "SELECT * FROM tipoprod";
$resulta = $conn->query($sql_tipo);

if ($resulta->num_rows > 0){

    while ( $row = $resulta->fetch_assoc()){            

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['id'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['codigo_produto'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['codigo_tipo'] .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['descricao'] .'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

conn.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost"; /* nome da conexão */
$username = "root"; /* nome do usuario da conexãp */
$password = ""; /*senha do banco de dados caso exista */
$dbname = "teste123"; /* nome do seu banco  */

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>
```

Comment: Oi Victor! Obrigado pela ajuda. Sendo que sou navegador de primeira viagem em desenvolvimento web, queria entender como funciona (verificar) o teu conn.php tentando relacionar essa tua sugestão ao meu site.

Comment: é basicamente um arquivo que voce cria com o nome que quiser, no meu caso é conn, e você inclui em todas as páginas que for utilizar conexão com o banco, ao invés de ficar criando conexão página a página. Vou editar a resposta com o arquivo conn.php

Comment: Fiz o teste usando o a sua sugestão mas não deu o resultado esperado. Veja as imágens <img src=" http://localhost/imgPv/imagStackOver1.png" width="200" height="100"> <br> <img src=" http://localhost/imgPv/imagStackOver2.png" width="400" height="100">

Comment: só abrir outra pergunta com seu código e sua dúvida que eu ajudo, comenta aqui o link da dúvida e se quiser adicionar imagem, selecione um ícone no cabeçalho de onde digita sua mensagem que tem um ícone de imagem

Comment: Ok, Victor! Só não sabia que, quando tem um código php inseido no html, o arquivo tem que pegar a exenção php. Feito isso, funcionou MARAVILHA. Valeu meu irmão!

Comment: sim você tem que dar sempre um include no arquivo de conexao, se o nome dele for exencao por exemplo, no começo do seu arquivo já abra  um bloco <?php include("conn.php); ?> e ai funcionara normal para a página toda

Comment: Ok Victor, mais um obrigado. Conto com o teu auxílio para o próximo obstaculo na realização do meu site onde será incluído um sistema bastante complexo em mecanismos de segurânça e interação com o usuário. Abraço.